# Phonegap sliding menubar or toolbar for android

Tags: android, cordova

I have to add one Toolbar at bottom of the page. I want to show only 2 menu items at a time,when user scrolls toolbar it should show me next menu items. Can somebody please do the needfull ?

Comment: Share something you've tried. If you want someone to do it for you there are plenty of freelancers around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jquery

Here is an exemple of jquery with toolbar

[here is the link](http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/)